# magento how checkout register method work

Tags: php, magento

i'm trying to understand how checkout register method work, what i need is to now when the customer is created, because i add an **alias** attribute to the customer and i want set this attribute equal to the name when the user register in the checkout, untill now i can't found how to do this, need some help

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Im understand your question correctly, you're going to want to look mostly at the class `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage`

Another option I believe would be writing your module to be triggered on a checkout event.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

1.4.1.x hook list, you can get the same list with a simple grep also...

http://watson-net.com/blog/magento-1-4-1-0-event-hooks/